# What is the 38;5 sequence in $PS1?

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors, history, ansi

I tried to find info online, but I could not find any. It seems that many people use a specific sequence of numbers, without actually providing any explanation why.

More specifically, my `$PS1` in bash is the following:

```
\[\033[38;5;21m\][\[\033[38;5;20m\]\u@\[\033[38;5;1m\]\h \W\[\033[38;5;21m\]]\[\033[0m\]\$
```

I cannot understand what is the `38;5` sequence. Does anybody knows that is the `38;5`?

**I know what is does**, but I do not know that is it! I mean, I know that I have to use it in order to assign the next value (i.e. 38;5;1m, the 1m is the next value) as the foreground colour and use values from 256 colours, but I do not know why 38 and why 5 and what other options are there and what these options represent.

For example, why after `38` we have to use either `5` or `2` and not `1` or `3`? Is there any general form that both the `38` and `48` codes correspond to? For example, is there any general form of code that is something like the `<code>;<switch>;<value>`which the `38` and `48` have?

Any help?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100975/discussion-on-question-by-xxxo-what-is-the-385-sequence-in-ps1).

Comment: See  ITU-T T.416 §13.1.8. Basically `5` is for indexed colors, and `2` for truecolor values, the remaining ones are hardly used in practice and hardly supported. There's a giant confusion around the separator (`;` or `:`), as well as `2` taking an additional parameter before the R, G, B values. See https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728 (including the enormous comment thread) for details.

Comment: @egmont - this is good information; can it be incorporated into roaima's answer, or into one of your own?

Comment: The `m` character is not part of the color value; it's the terminator that says there are no more color values coming after it. The `[` ... `m` code is called SGR (Select Graphic Rendition), a good readable guide is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally the codes came from DEC as part of their VT52/VT100/VT220 series serial display consoles. These were later standardised as part of ECMA and ANSI, and over time extended.

You can see one such early [ECMA standards document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-48,%202nd%20Edition,%20August%201979.pdf) from 1979, specifically page 40 of the document (page 48 of the PDF file) section 7.2.63 SGR. The `ESC [ 38` sequence is reserved for future use. These [colour tables](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) are that future use.

Comment: 3 foreground or background, never remember which is which, 8 the colour.

Comment: And the document doesn't define anything past 47 either, so it seems it's partly that 38 and 48 were free, which is often quite an important point in picking magic numbers... And the fact that both 38 and 48 kinda fit as extensions to the sequence of the basic color codes. That still doesn't explain why they used `5`, which already means "slow blink", though. That seems like an arbitrary choice. I don't know the actual history, I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: @ilkkachu it was quite possibly driven by hardware decoding, like the original sequences. But I also don't have a definitive answer.

Comment: You linked to an older edition of ECMA-48 instead of the latest one at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf. This latest one at least points you to ITU-T T.416 where these are further specied at §13.1.8.

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed what I wanted.

Comment: @egmont I'm very happy for you to add that later link to this answer (along with your [other comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551933/what-is-the-385-sequence-in-ps1/551940?noredirect=1#comment1024660_551933) referencing the ITU), but I would like the old one kept as part of my answer to help demonstrate some of the history of these standards.